# Parsing posted object array, Express

Tags: node.js, express, post

I need to parse data with Express from form:

```
invoiceRouter.post('/', async (req,res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let invoice = new Invoice();
  invoice = req.body;
  invoice.status = 0;
  //save
  res.redirect('/invoices');
});
```

When I log, the array of objects is read as list of values:

```
{
createdDate: '2021-10-15',
invoiceRows: [ 'Title3', '2', 'Title2', '3' ]
}
```

But it can not read the invoiceRows as array of 2, therefore I am struggling to parse it into array for saving it.
When I set the `extended: false`, I can see following result from req.body:

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  createdDate: '2021-10-15',
  'invoiceRows[0].productTitle': 'Title2',
  'invoiceRows[0].unitPrice': '2',
  'invoiceRows[1].productTitle': 'Title3',
  'invoiceRows[1].unitPrice': '2'
}
```

The schema I am using:

```
const invoiceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdDate: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    invoiceRows: [{
      productTitle: String,
      unitPrice: Number
    }]
});
```

Question: what am I doing wrong, in order to get array of objects from req.body inside parent object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your req.body you should be receiving like bellow (As per your model schema). Make your front end to send data like bellow.

```
 {
   createdDate: '2021-10-15',
   invoiceRows: [ { productTitle :'Title1', unitPrice : 2}, { productTitle :'Title2', unitPrice : 3} ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was on the frontend. I needed to use square brackets in the name field around property "productTitle" like this:
`<input required type="text" value="<%= invoice.invoiceRows[key].productTitle %>" name="invoiceRows[<%= key %>].[productTitle]" class="form-control">`